# Make FreeRDP prompt user for username and password ?

Tags: bash, prompt, rdp, freerdp

I got a problem with my rdp connection. I try to connect to my external server with zenity & Xfreerdp. I make a prompt inspired by : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119880/make-freerdp-prompt-user-for-username-and-password.

Here is my prompt :

```
    #!/bin/bash
Blank=$""

#--------------------------RECUPERATION DONNEES SERVEUR :

Home=$"/home/user/serveur"
if [ -f $Home ]; then
       Test=$(<$Home)
       if [ "$Test" != "$Blank" ]; then
               Serveur=$(<$Home)
               Optionnel="$Serveur"
       else
               Optionnel=$"Optionnel"
       fi
fi

#--------------------------RECUPERATION DONNEES PSEUDO :

Home1=$"/home/user/pseudo"
if [ -f $Home1 ]; then
       Test1=$(<$Home1)
       if [ "$Test1" != "$Blank" ]; then
               Pseudo=$(<$Home1)
               Optionnel1=$"$Pseudo"
       else
               Optionnel1=$"optionnel"
       fi
fi

#------------------------------Domaine

Home2=$"/home/user/domaine"
Optionnel2=$(<$Home2)

#----------------------------RECUPERATION DONNEES PASSERELLE :

Home3=$"/home/user/Passerelle"
Optionnel3=$(<$Home3)

#----------------------------RECUPERATION DONNEES APP :

Home4=$"/home/user/app"

####################----------------------------RDP-----------------------#####$

#-----------------------------DEFINIT L'AFFICHAGE DE LA FENETRE

OUTPUT=$(zenity --forms --title="INFORMATIONS DE CONNEXION" \
   --text="ENTREZ VOS INFORMATIONS DE CONNEXION" \
   --separator="," \
   --add-entry="serveur ($Optionnel)" \
   --add-entry="port (defaut : 3389)" \
   --add-entry="domaine ($oOptionnel2)" \
   --add-entry="passerelle ($Optionnel3)" \
   --add-entry="pseudo ($Optionnel1)" \
   --add-password="mot de passe" \
   --add-entry="remote app (Optionnel)")
OUTPUT_RESULTS=$?

#-----------------------------SI LE FORMULAIRE EST VIDE

if ((OUTPUT_RESULTS != 0)); then
   echo "ERREUR SUR LE FORMULAIRE"
   exit 1
fi

#-----------------------------SERVEUR

Tempserveur=$(awk -F, '{print $1}' <<<$OUTPUT)
if [ "$Tempserveur" != "$Blank" ]; then
       Serveur=$"$Tempserveur"
fi

#-----------------------------PORT (FACULTATIF)

Port=$(awk -F, '{print $2}' <<<$OUTPUT)
if [ "$Port" = "$Blank" ]
then
   Port="3389"
else
   Port="$Port"
fi

#------------------------------DOMAINE

Domaine=$(awk -F, '{print $3}' <<<$OUTPUT)
if [ "$Domaine" != "$Blank" ]; then
       exit
else

#------------------------------PASSERELLE (FACULTATIF OU RENVOIE VERS UN FICHIE$
#####FICHIER EXERTNE

Passerelle=$(awk -F, '{print $4}' <<<$OUTPUT)
if  [ "$Passerelle" = "$Blank" ]; then
   Passerelle=$(</home/user/Passerelle)
   echo "$Passerelle"
   Passerelle="$Passerelle"
fi
######SANS PASSERELLE
if [ "$Passerelle" = "$Blank" ]
then
   echo "PAS DE PASSERELLE DEFINIE"
else
   echo "$Passerelle" > "$Home3"
   Passerelle="/G:$Passerelle"
fi

#-----------------------------PSEUDO

Temppseudo=$(awk -F, '{print $5}' <<<$OUTPUT)
if [ "$Temppseudo" != "$Blank" ]; then
       Pseudo=$"$Temppseudo"
fi

#-----------------------------MOT DE PASSE

Password=$(awk -F, '{print $6}' <<<$OUTPUT)
App=$(awk -f, '{print $7}' <<<$OUTPUT)
if ["$App" = "$Blank"]
then
   App="$App"
   Title="$Serveur"
else
   Appname="$App"
   Title="$Appname on $Serveur"
   App="/app:||$App"

fi

#-----------------------------SAUVEGARDES

echo "$Serveur" > "$Home"
echo "$Pseudo" > "$Home1"
echo "$Domaine" > "$Home2"
echo "$App" > "$Home4"

#-----------------------------COMMANDE FREERDP

#zenity --info --title="information return" --text="$Serveur $Port $Domaine $Passerelle $Pseudo $Password"
echo "XFREERDP $Title $Serveur $Port $Domaine $Passerelle $Pseudo $Password $App"
xfreerdp /t:"$Title" /v:$Serveur:$Port /d:$Domaine /g:$Passerelle /u:$Pseudo /p:$Password
Password=""
```

And he return :

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZkbq.png)

Thank's for you help

-A french rookie-